# how can I format string like 9:34, 18:00 to format of 00:00

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am gathering time in different forms like 9:34, 18:00. these are strings and I need to keep them strings, while keeping sure they are always following format of "00:00"

Comment: `('0'+time).slice(-5)`

Comment: You can start by writing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it just the matter of adding leading `0`. This will work

```
var str = "9:45";
('0'+str).slice(-5); //09:45

var str = "19:45";
('0'+str).slice(-5); //19:45
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex

```js
var time = '9:34, 19:00:01, 18:00';

document.write(time
               .replace(/\b\d:\d{2}(\b|:)/g, '0$&')
               // for replacing time in format X:XX to 0X:XX
               .replace(/(\b\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}\b/g, '$1')
               // for replacing time in format XX:XX:XX to XX:XX
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

If the minute and second parts are also unpredictable, then you would need to fix that as well.

```js
var t1 = '9:3';
    
var t2 = t1.split(':').map(function(part) {
  return ('0' + part).slice(-2);
}).join(':');
    
console.log(t2);
```